# Jersey+jackson - how to serialize generic list

Tags: json, serialization, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I have a problem with converting my lists to JSON. I'd like to use generic lists with templating.

This doesn't work for me. My POJO:

```
class Event {
    private Long id;
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Generic list result:

```
public class ListResponse<T> {
    private List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    public List<T> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<T> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Concrete list result:

```
public class EventListResponse extends ListResponse<Event> {}
```

In my resource class I'm using this:

```
@PermitAll
@Path("/list")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public EventListResponse getEvents() {
    //...
    EventListResponse response = new EventListResponse();
    List<Event> events = eventService.getList();
    response.setResult(events);
    return response;
}
```

The serialize doesnt work in this case, I end up with Strings insead of "Event" JSON objects.

I get results like:

```
array(3) { ["type"]=> string(17) "eventListResponse" ["result"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(38) "com.mypackage.model.Event@3a622482" } }
```

Whats the problem here?

Thank you

Comment: Works fine for me with Jersey 2.16 and `jersey-media-json-jackson` 2.16. What Jersey and Jackson version are you using? Can you show your dependencies.

Comment: Interesting, I was using moxy, which didnt work, but I switched to your dependency and now it works. :) Thanks for the tip